# Action every 5 loop and also the remainder at the end?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

This is my basic code that do action every loop.

```
find sample -mmin -60 |
while read -r file
do
  nohup bash "script.sh" "$file" >> log.out &
  echo "File $i : $file"
  i+=1
done
```

But this is too resource consuming - creating new process for each sample. So, I am thinking to start action after reading 5 files. But, I got no idea how to effectively doing the remainder at the end.

```
find sample -mmin -60 |
{
while read -r file
do
  getfile[$i]="$file"
  if ((i % 5 == 0))
    nohup bash "script.sh" "${getfile[$i-4]}" "${getfile[$i-3]}" "${getfile[$i-2]}" "${getfile[$i-1]}" "${getfile[$i]}" >> log.out &
    echo "File $i : "${getfile[$i-4]}" "${getfile[$i-3]}" "${getfile[$i-2]}" "${getfile[$i-1]}" "${getfile[$i]}""
  fi
    i+=1
done

##This is the part that I don't know what to do effectively, what if the remainder files are only 4, 3, 2, or 1
if ((i % 5 != 0))
then
  nohup bash "script.sh" "${getfile[$i-3]}" "${getfile[$i-2]}" "${getfile[$i-1]}" "${getfile[$i]}" >> log.out &
  echo "File $i : "${getfile[$i-3]}" "${getfile[$i-2]}" "${getfile[$i-1]}" "${getfile[$i]}""
fi

}
```

Comment: Look at `xargs -n5`

Comment: `xargs -P5` might be even more sensible, with a `-n` tuned based on the amount of permissible slop at/around the edge of the batch.

Comment: Did you use `declare -i i`? If not, `i+=1` doesn't do what you think it does.